# How to disable Trickle Timer in Contiki-NG?

Tags: contiki, contiki-ng, rpl

I have one question for you. I want to disable the trickle timer in the `rpl-mrhof.c` file. I defined one flag name as `Trickle_flag`. I want to disable the Trickle timer in my program when the `Trickle_flag` is equal to 1 and the DIO transmissions will be suppressed. When the `Trickle_flag` is equal to 0 the DIO transmissions will be continued. I want to stop all node's DIO transmissions. Any idea how to change the trickle function?

Comment: Hello, everyone. I tried to follow this instruction from the trickle-timer.h file as below :
A trickle timer is considered 'stopped' when
  i_cur == TRICKLE_TIMER_IS_STOPPED.
 trickle_timer_stop() must be used to correctly disable a trickle timer.
 Do NOT set the value of i_cur to 0 directly, as this will fail to stop the timer. But I don't know where should I change the code. Any help is useful for me.

Comment: I also set #define TRICKLE_TIMER_COMPENSATE_DRIFT 1 in my project-conf.h

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way how to disable a trickle timer is to call the `trickle_timer_stop(tt)` macro, where `tt` is the timer to stop. See [the documentation](https://contiki-ng.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_api/group__trickle-timer.html#gaa475b1b9b3edd81df04d290bd34d7e72) of this macro.

Stopping DIO transmissions is a different question though. The Contiki RPL implementation was developed before the Trickle timer library existed, so it does not use the Trickle timer API, but instead implements the Trickle timers internally, through callback timers (`struct ctimer`). Don't use `ctimer_stop(&instance->dio_timer)` for this either, it will not give reliable results, as the `rpl_reset_dio_timer` function may be called by some events, which will restart the timer. Your best approach is filter out the DIO messages before they are sent, instead of messing with the Trickle timers in a way that's not expected by the developers of the code. You can add an if statement to `dio_output` based on the flag value, for example, to return immediately if the DIO suppression flag is set.